# How iterate by one after another in Thymeleaf- Spring - Boot?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

How can we iterate a list on Thymeleaf page? Suppose I have a list which contains an object

I am able to display all the user info one after another on the Thymeleaf page, but this is actually what I don't want to implement. Is there any way so that I can display one user at a time and there will be two buttons on the next button click move to the next available user and display info and hide the previous user info and when the previous button is clicked move back to previous one. As  I more than 20+ or even sometimes 50+ users information.

```
public class Info {
private String name;
private String dob;
private String university;
// constructor , getter and setter
}
```

my controller class

```
@GetMapping("/get/All-user-info")
public String getAllUserInfo(Model model){
  List<Info> info = new ArrayList<>();
info.add(new Info("NA","22/02/2020","Florida"));
info.add(new Info("PA","22/01/2020","Florida"));
info.add(new Info("CA","22/03/2020","Florida"));
info.add(new Info("DA","22/04/2020","Florida"));
model.addAttribute("info",info);
return "page-thyme";
}
```

my Thymeleaf page look like. It displays all the in one go. I really don't understand what to do here.

```
<div th:each="info, status : ${info}">
<p th:text="${info.name}">
<p th:text="${info.dob}">
<p th:text="${info.university}">
</div>
```

Edit:
I have added a service class

```
@GetMapping("/get/All-user-info/{departmentId}")
public String getAllUserInfo(Model model, @PathVariable String departmentId){
  List<Info> info = userService.getUser(departmentId);
model.addAttribute("info",info);
return "page-thyme";
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a Thymeleaf question, _per se_ - I think it's more of a _"how to implement pagination in Spring Boot?_ question. Thymeleaf can _support_ pagination solutions, but does not _provide_ such solutions. I think researching "Spring Boot pagination" may be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the index of the object in parameter of your contoller like this:

```
@GetMapping (path = "/modal")
public String modal(Model model, @RequestParam(name = "page", defaultValue = "0") int page) {
    List<Info> info = new ArrayList<>();
    
    info.add(new Info("NA","22/02/2020","Florida"));
    info.add(new Info("PA","22/01/2020","Florida"));
    info.add(new Info("CA","22/03/2020","Florida"));
    info.add(new Info("DA","22/04/2020","Florida"));
    model.addAttribute("info",info);
    model.addAttribute("index",page);
    return "modal";
}
```

and add a sort of pagination in your HTML page:

```
<div >
  <p th:text="${info[__${index}__].name}">
  <p th:text="${info[__${index}__].dob}">
  <p th:text="${info[__${index}__].university}">
  <div th:each="info, status : ${info}"><a th:text="${status.index}" th:href="@{modal(page=${status.index})}"></a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thankyou Xtof, but I do have a question suppose I have ```info``` list which will come from the already deployed rest API, so every time it has to interact with its API I think that's not the right approach what you say? Can you explain what does it mean in ```[__${x}__]``` as I am very new into it.

Comment: Hi @Xtof, I just made additional changes to the question, please look if you can help. Is there a way I can use the whole list in one go and iterate it on Thymeleaf only

Comment: @AyushKangar - `__${x}__` is Thymeleaf's [pre-processing syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#preprocessing).

Comment: @AyushKangar - You commented: _every time it has to interact with its API_ - yes it would have to do that. Thymeleaf cannot handle client-side user-triggered paging all by itself. It is not that type of tool. The good news is: you are using Spring, and Spring provides support for paging.

Comment: Hi @AyushKangar, answers to your questions have been done by andrewjames. Just an additional comment if you want to use pagination with Spring: Your returned type in your controller will be Page<Info> instead of List<Info>. Make some tests and ask a new question if needed, otherwise it will become questions within a question...